# Расположение элементов flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть код:

```css
.menu {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.menu__category li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
.menu__category a {
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  color: black;
}
.menu__category a:hover {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ec4e4e;
  color: #ec4e4e;
}
.menu__social i {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease;
}
.menu__social i:hover {
  color: #ec4e4e;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="menu__category">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Главная</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Новинки</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu__social">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при уменьшени экрана (на планшете, допустим) логотип и ссылки были в один ряд, а меню переносилось на следующий. Не знаю как реализовать.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам по сути нужна отдельная разметка с media-query под маленькие разрешения (к примеру, возьмём до `800px` в ширине).

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu {
    /* Чтобы header мог занимать много строк */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .menu__category {
    /* Чтобы меню занимало всю строку */
    width: 100%;
    /* Чтобы меню было в самом конце */
    /* можете поставить другое число, главное >= 1 */
    order: 9999;
  }
}
```

Весь пример

```css
.menu {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.menu__category li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
.menu__category a {
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  color: black;
}
.menu__category a:hover {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ec4e4e;
  color: #ec4e4e;
}
.menu__social i {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease;
}
.menu__social i:hover {
  color: #ec4e4e;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .menu__category {
    width: 100%;
    order: 9999;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="menu__category">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Главная</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Новинки</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu__social">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Также можно улучшить данный пример, добавив в общие стили (не внутрь media query):

```css
.menu__category ul {
  /* Чтобы меню гарантированно было на одной строке */
  /* Так как по умолчанию стоит flex-wrap: nowrap; для flexbox */
  display: flex;
  /* Удалить padding для ul по умолчанию */
  padding: 0;
  /* Расположить контент по центру */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

На мобильных устройствах также можно уменьшить `padding` для `.menu__category ul li`, например, установив меньше значение (`10px`, `5px` и т.д.) или просто установить в процентах. Также можно уменьшить или удалить `padding` для `.menu`.